# notepad++. replace dot and space with carriage return

Tags: notepad++

The title says it all.
I want to change a sequence like

```
(I am a human. Are you?)
```

to

```
(I am a human.
Are you?)
```

I tried replacing .\s with \n but weird things happen that is not the intended outcome.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find what: `.`   (dot and space)

Replace with: `.\r\n` (there are no spaces inside this)

Search mode: **Extended**